# Visio 2013 - Glue Lines to Shape

Tags: microsoft-visio

If I create a square shape and then add line shapes to create a grid how do I glue the line connection points to the square so when I change the shape of the square the lines change also. At the moment I'm using the 'join' command which makes them a single shape. But when I grab the pencil and try to change the position of the square corner the lines don't move with it. Am I using the wrong tool?

Answer (score 0):

If you click the "X" Icon to the right of the "Connection" Icon in the menu
and then select the shape you want a Connection Point at and then hold CTRL while clicking where on the shape you want a Connection Point it should do the trick.

Like this:

1. Click the "X":

[image]

2. Click on your shape, then hold CTRL and click where you want the Connection Point:
   [image]
3. All done, drag a Connection between your shape and some other shape:
   [image]

The same applies if you want to do lines internally in the shape.

[image]